# How to use one link to authorize users for tenants with admin consent and without?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We have an app that uses Office365 OAuth to register and authenticate users.

There are two types of tenant that are using the app.
One type is "Microsoft/Azure tenant is configured to restrict non-admin users" and another one allows to authorize without any restrictions.

For the second type users use this link:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...prompt=consent
```

For the first type we are using admin consent link:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent
```

After that ordinary users use this link without `prompt=consent`:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...
```

Is there a way for non admin users to use one link? 
Or what is the best UX approach in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You might not need to use `prompt=consent` at all.

Based on my testing, you should be able to use a URL like:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=aaaabbbb-44fb-47e3-a69d-f8c29cfdf49b&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080&scope=Calendars.Read%20User.Read
```

If the tenant does not allow users to consent for themselves, they get this error:

[image: Admin consent required error]

If they have an admin account, they can click the link there.

If they click the other link to return to your app, they will be redirected back with a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/?error=access_denied&error_subcode=cancel&add_account=
```

You could show the user a view explaining the situation, and give them a link that they can also copy, which their admin could then use to consent for their organisation. That link would then go to the admin consent URL.